# Outer join in subquery does not return value

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, outer-join

Let's say I have a table like this:

Main table:

```
id | value
-----------
1  | 'not null'
```

Joined table:

```
id | value
-----------
2  | 'id does not match, whatever'
```

And a select statement like this:

```
SELECT
  m.value without_join,
  (SELECT
     m.value with_join
   FROM
     joined_table j
   WHERE
     j.id(+) = m.id) joined
FROM
  main_table m;
```

The returned result is as follows:

```
without_join | with_join
-------------------------
not null     | (null)
```

Inner join is performed instead of outer join even though I joined with `(+)` operator. As no rows are select in subquery, instead of `m.value` null value is returned.

The behavior I expected was to outer join `j` to `m` in subquery and therefore return not null value from `m` table.

Comment: Ok, and do you have an idea why `SELECT * FROM main_table m` returns a row and `SELECT * FROM main_table m JOIN joined_table j ON m.id = j.id` does not return any row?

Comment: Radim, I do. However, the following statement: `SELECT * FROM main_table m LEFT OUTER JOIN joined_table j ON m.id = j.id` returns some rows. What I do not understand is why inner join is performed in subselect instead of outer join.

Comment: This seems like a valid (although very dated) question.  I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: Why does what differ from what why should they be the same? PS [mcve] PS Even Oracle says, don't use `(+)`, use `left join`. Although you aren't using `(+)` with `,` so it has no effect. Read the manual re left joins. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you understand why this would return `NULL`:

```
SELECT m.value as without_join,
       (SELECT m.value with_join
        FROM joined_table j
        WHERE j.id = m.id
       ) as joined
FROM main_table m;
```

The inner join has no match.

I can understand your logic.  It goes like:

- The subquery is doing an outer join (although one without explicit `join` syntax).
- It should keep all values of `m`, filling in `j` will `NULL` values for non-matches.
- The subquery is returning one row.
- The subquery is selecting a column from `m`, so it should be in the result set.

This doesn't work.  This outer join syntax (apparently) works when `j` and `m` are in the same `FROM` clause.

A subquery is implementing an outer join *anyway*.  My simple guess is that the designers of the syntax did not implement consider functionality for subqueries, because the subquery is already an outer join.  At this point, documentation on `(+)` is at least 20 years old, so it is rather difficult to figure out such intentions.

Oracle superseded the `(+)` syntax two decades ago.  My advice is simply not to use it.  It is not the recommended syntax for outer joins.  And it is not needed for subqueries.

Comment: What are "A subquery is implementing an outer join" & "the subquery is already an outer join" supposed to mean?

Comment: @philipxy . . . A correlated subquery is keeping all the rows in the outer table along with matching values from the inner table.  This is equivalent to an outer join (albeit one limited to one row per match).  The syntax does not use `JOIN`, but it is functionally equivalent to an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting elements from Main table, and then selecting elements from the the joined table where the id in the second table matches the id of the item from the main table. Since there is no element in the second table with id: 1, there is no match in the other table, so the result is null.